# Can someone help in reversing this equation?

Tags: logarithms

I have Tf1(ADC1), but need to find out ADC1

[image]

Comment: Is  Tf1 a function  and ACD1  a variable?

Comment: @mrnovice yes. So in the above equation if i assume ADC = 1, i'll get Tf1(ADC1) as -98. All good. Now what i need is when i have -98 with me and don't have the value of ADC.

Comment: ok, well have a look at the answer I wrote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f = Tf_{1}$, let $x = ACD_{1}$

We have $$f(x) = \frac{9}{\frac{\ln(\frac{c}{x}-\frac{1}{5})}{676}+d}-459.67$$

with $c = 207.08502024291497975584, d= 0.016770082173402649673$

$$(\frac{\ln(\frac{c}{x}-\frac{1}{5})}{676}+d)f(x) = 9 - 459.67(\frac{\ln(\frac{c}{x}-\frac{1}{5})}{676}+d)$$

$$(f(x)+459.67)(\frac{\ln(\frac{c}{x}-\frac{1}{5})}{676})= 9 -459.67d -df(x)$$

$$\frac{\ln(\frac{c}{x}-\frac{1}{5})}{676} = \frac{ 9 -459.67d -df(x)}{f(x)+459.67}$$

$$\frac{c}{x}-\frac{1}{5} = e^{ \frac{676( 9 -459.67d -df(x))}{f(x)+459.67}}$$

$$\frac{c}{x} = \frac{5e^{ \frac{676( 9 -459.67d -df(x))}{f(x)+459.67}}+1}{5}$$

$$x = \frac{5c}{5e^{ \frac{676( 9 -459.67d -df(x))}{f(x)+459.67}}+1}$$

Comment: @RobinCSamuel  I don't understand what you mean - what exactly do you want?

Comment: Hey sorry! was a confusion. this works!!